# Hiding partially downloaded files

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

When you download a torrent where you only need one, or few of the items there, you get a folder filled to the brim with .part files. This absolutely clutters the folder view and makes it very hard to navigate/use.

Is there a way in nautilus to hide .part files, or any file extension?

Comment: Unfortunately, they get redownloaded by the torrent if you delete them, since they are part of the "chunk" that the one file you needed was in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: *Technically* the answer to your question is "Yes". *Practically* the answer is "No".

You can hide files by creating a `.hidden` file in the directory where you would like to not see certain files. The problem is that the `.hidden` file does not accept wildcards, so you cannot say `*.part`. Instead, you would have to have each individual file added to the `.hidden` file ... and this is *per directory*. So if your Torrents are going to multiple directories, you will need multiple `.hidden` files, each with their own list of specific files to exclude.

There are extensions you can add to Nautilus to build these files for you, such as [Nautilus Hide](https://github.com/brunonova/nautilus-hide)¹, but the `.hidden` file is only read the first time you enter the directory. This means you would have to quit Nautilus and restart the application if you wanted to not see any `.part` files. This is anything but an ideal solution.

---

¹ the Nautilus Hide extension has been abandoned for several years and archived by its creator. I have no idea if this will work on modern versions of the Nautilus file manager or not. Caveat Emptor, and all that ...

Comment: In order for the `.hidden` file "feature" to work in _Nautilus_ you have to have the **Show Hidden Files** option deselected (version 40.2 of _Files_).